# how to protect flash videos from being downloaded, ripped?

Tags: flash, video

How would you be able to stop people from downloading flash video from your site instead of viewing it in a flash player. I would like to prevent people from downloading the flash video by ripping the stream.

I am not looking for 100% prevention but ways to make this difficult and annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe's Flash Media Streaming Server software has some security features which can encrypt the stream. This may not be 100%, being that anything displayed on a client's screen can probably be broken, but check it out and see if it will help in your application.

[Flash Media Streaming Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediastreaming/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is 100% secure way to prevent the users from downloading whatever they see on their devices (like the flash videos). There are ways to make it hard on average users, but it won't prevent the expert users from doing it.

One way to make it annoying/hard for people to download your flash movies is by splitting the flash movie into smaller parts, which (each part) on loading delete the previously loaded part.

Comment: I am looking for ways to make it annoying and difficult....I know 100% prevention is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no method to stop this. Every data you send to client can be saved.

Answer (score 1):

As John mentioned, Adobe Flash Media Server provides a security feature when you are streaming a flash video. You can stream the video using RTMPE protocol. This will ensure that your video packets are encrypted and also the channel between your Adobe FMS and the client is also encrypted. There are tools in the market which can rip the video streamed with the earlier version of RTMPE protocol, but Adobe makes sure that it revises the protocol regularly, and i recently tried ripping the rtmpe streamed video with almost all the flash rippers available in the market, its pretty safe and cheap.
Hope that helps.